# when using git cherry-pick, How can we get my commit , conflict with which commit?

Tags: git, github, version-control

when using git cherry-pick,occur a conflict.
the conflict cause by the target branch is short of the work branch.
lack of some commit ,I can't cherry-pick my new commit to the target branch .
the question is how can i find which conflict commit , When i cherry-pick my new commit to target branch which is lack of some commit, and list the confilct commit ID ?

I m sorry for my pool English.

```
Branch A, whith commit 1,2,3,4,5,6
Branch B, with commit  1,3
```

commit 6 is a associate with commit 4. 
when I cherry-pick commit 6 to branch B, the conflict occur.

Is there have any easy way to figure out which commit is associate commit 6.
so that i can cherry-pick this commit (like commit 4),and than cherry-pick commit 6, instead of commit 4 & 5 both.

Thank you for all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42531657/2303202

Comment: @SITU what do you mean commit 6 is a associate with commit 4? Do you mean both 4 and 6 modify the same files or 6 is merged from 4? BTW, even it shows conflicts during rebase, you can solve the conflicts manually or automatically to finish the cherry-pick. And it will be more clear if you illustrate your branches structure by grah.

Comment: modify the same files. like @Mort say, i want to find a more efficient way

Comment: @SITU I give the answer to find the earliest commit which add/modified a certain file. Please have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the commit which original add/change a file on branch `A` before cherry-pick. You can use:

```
git log B..A filename
```

This command will output the commits which modified the file and the commits only belongs to branch `A`. You can find the earliest commit in the bottom of output, and then cherry-pick this commit on branch `B`:

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick <the earliest commit you found>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to edit your question, but the edit was so complete, that I would have rewritten your original question.

Perhaps it is this:

"When attempting to `git cherry-pick A`, I get a conflict. This conflict is because commit `B`, an ancestor of `A` is not in the destination branch and without it, commit `A` results in massive conflicts in the destination branch. How do I identify commit `B`?"

This is not a git question, this is a general revision control question. There might be just one commit that blocks `A` from going into the destination branch cleanly (or even with small conflicts) or there might be several commits blocking `A`. Look at the conflicts when doing the cherry-pick, and look at all the files changed in `A`, and do a `git log A -- <file>` on each and try to figure out what would fix that conflict. Then try cherry-picking various combinations `git cherry-pick B A` until you find something that works.

Comment: thank you very much. that is a way to fingure out .but ,When A  has large files changed, it is too hard to do this. especially  many commit is associate with A.

Comment: Hard problems have hard solutions. In your example above, the programmatical approach to solving the problem is to figure out all commits not in `B` : `(2,4,5)`, and try all combinations of them (including multiple ones) to see what makes `6` go in.